# problem using verbatim package?

Tags: biblatex, xetex, pdftex, tex-core

I am trying to print a .tex code in a pdf file. I am using **verbatim** package for this. but this package automatically breaks the line but I don't want to break the line.
my output should be something like this.
[image]

but my output is something like this 
[image]

Comment: Use \verb+\appendix+ instead of verbatim.

Comment: The `verbatim` environment always starts a new paragraph. If you want to use a verbatim string inside a paragraph you can use something like  `\verb|\appendix|`.

Comment: And next time, please cut and paste your code instead of sticking in images.

Comment: @JPi I have edited the question is it ok now
?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a basic feature explained in any introduction.

Comment: do as you wish now I know how to do that so do whatever you want with this question